# I cant get my sh script to run at boot in rc.local

Tags: ubuntu, startup

Here is my /etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sh /home/ubuntu/Desktop/camset.sh
exit 0
```

When I cd into /etc and run /home/ubuntu/Desktop/camset.sh, the script runs fine.  The script just sets camera filters with v4l2-ctl.  Is it possible that the camera is not yet connected/setup when the script runs? I have also made sure to make the script executable with chmod.

UPDATE:
Here is my new rc.local file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/usr/bin/screen -dmS autostart bash -c '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/camset.sh'
deflog on
logfile /tmp/screenlog_$USER_.%H.%n.%Y%m%d-%0c:%s.%t.log
exit 0
```

The only things in the tmp/ directory are:
config-err-sHJlFD  unity_support_test.0

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons, and we don't know what your script is doing. What I would do is add some logging to find out what's happening.

See for example: [Where is log file from rc.local?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434242/where-is-log-file-from-rc-local)

The other approach (that I prefer) is to use the [screen command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/) to launch the process in its own terminal session.

Prerequisite:

```
apt-get install screen
```

Then you can add something like this to your local.rc file

```
/usr/bin/screen -dmS autostart bash -c '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/camset.sh'
```

In order to keep a log of the screen console also create a file /root/.screenrc like this:

```
deflog on
logfile /tmp/screenlog_$USER_.%H.%n.%Y%m%d-%0c:%s.%t.log
```

After reboot you can check the log file (in this example it's stored in /tmp).

PS: you may have to add an ampersand (&) after your script if it doesn't return, it could prevent the computer from booting.

Note that rc.local will be executed as root.

Comment: I tried this but there was no log file created

Comment: If you type: screen -ls does it say "No Sockets found..." or something else ?

Comment: No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps /usr/bin/screen is not the correct path on your system, check with:
which screen
and adapt if necessary

Comment: which screen returns "/usr/bin/screen"

Comment: I suppose rc.local is executable too ? (chmod +x)
What happens if you try:
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start

The service may be disabled by default on newer versions of Ubuntu. To activate it: sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service